How do I understand that there is no infinitesimal element in $\mathbb{R}$?
I read a problem in my book that if there is an element $o>0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, such that for any $x>0$, we will have $o<x$, and we call $o$ as an infinitesimal element. Prove that there is no infinitesimal element in $\mathbb{R}$.
But if there are no infinitesimal elements in real numbers, then how do I define limits in real numbers?
I'm not sure if this is a clerical error on the part of the questioner, who was maybe trying to write that there is no infinitesimal element in $\mathbb{Q}$, or maybe I didn't understand it correctly.

Is $o/2$ in $\Bbb{R}$?  If you want to have "reals with infinitesimals", see nonstandard analysis.  This is not analysis on the reals; it is analysis on a different set.

As well as Eric's point of $o / 2$, you have said that $o \in \mathbb{R}^+$ but also $o < x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$.  So, $o < o$.

Thanks a lot,I seem a lot clearer

@EricTowers, you claim that nonstandard analysis is "not analysis on the reals but rather analysis on a different set" but this depends on the presentation of nonstandard analysis.  In its model-theoretic presentation (via, e.g., hyperreal extensions), this would be correct.  However, in its axiomatic presentation, nonstandard analysis is done in the usual $\mathbb R$ and infinitesimals are found there; see my answer.

The claim that "there are no infinitesimals in $\mathbb R$" depends on a number of unspoken assumptions, chief among them being that one agrees to work in set theory based on a language limited to the $\in$-language, namely language limited to the membership relation, which is the language of a theory such as Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory with choice (ZFC).
If one works with a richer language such as the st-$\in$ language of a theory like SPOT, then one can have infinitesimals in $\mathbb R$; see this recent article:

Hrbacek, K.; Katz, M. "Infinitesimal analysis without the Axiom of Choice." Annals of Pure and Applied Logic 172 (2021), no. 6, 102959. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2021.102959, https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.04980, https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=4224071

Here "st" is the standardness predicate, i.e., the one-place predicate declaring whether an entity is standard or not.

You don’t use infinitesimal numbers to define limits in $\mathbb{R}$. As a matter of fact, when you use $\varepsilon - \delta$ formalism, you are implied to use arbitrary values of $\varepsilon$ to claim if the limit exists.
I guess your problem is easy to solve by stating that such an element $\omicron$ exists and then constructing an element that is on the real line yet is less than the aforementioned infinitesimal number.

But what is the difference between $\mathbb{\epsilon}$ and infinitesimal numbers?
If we are using $\epsilon-\delta$ to define limits, then we are consider that $\epsilon>0$, but actually all number minus $\epsilon$ is not something like zero. So it's looks like a kind of infinitesimal.

In the real analysis use of $\epsilon$, it is an "ordinary" small number like $0.1$ or $0.001$ - the only trick is that the definition of a limit requires the correct behavior no matter whether we pick $\epsilon=0.1$ or $\epsilon=0.001$ or something smaller. Once $\epsilon$ is picked, however, we can treat it like any other real number.

Thanks, so $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ refer to the range that I can accept, in my future analysis?

@Young, I would suggest taking a look at the very nature of $\varepsilon$ and $\omicron$. The latter, as your definition suggests, is once and for all fixed an element of the space. You don’t have to do extra work with it. Conversely, when you use $\varepsilon$ to investigate limits, it’s only a matter of choice for this constant to analyse further. If the limit indeed exists, whatever $\varepsilon$ is valid.

Suppose there exists $o\in\mathbb R$ such that $0<o<x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.
I would argue that, since $o\in\mathbb R$ by hypothesis, it would follow that $o<o$. Contradiction.
Also, any $x\in\mathbb R_+$ is greater than $x/2$.
